# Why use while loop to create and close MessageBox will take more and more memory?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

## Environment

Windows 10, IDE : Visual Studio 2022 .

## Question

I just run a very simple code as follow.

```
#include"Windows.h"
int main(){
    while (true) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"hello world!!!", L"hello", MB_OK);
    } //set break point here
}
```

Use visual studio's debug mode to capture the memory snapshot , I found snapshot show that `Heap Size` always increase after some loop. What's wrong with my code? Should I use some code to release `MessageBox()`? Or is this a bug of visual studio?

Comment: Well you are not closing it, just creating more and mode MessageBoxes, as your cycle runs forever.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code. No, there is no code to release a MessageBox, No, there is no bug here.

Comment: @defaultUsernameN MessageBox pauses until the user closes it.

Comment: @anywayName What's wrong here is your expectations. You think that when you close a MessageBox windows should release all memory immediately. But why do you think that?  Maybe Windows will release the memory later. Maybe Windows is allocating more memory to your program because it's creating so many message boxes. Probably the heap size you are seeing is the amount of memory Windows has allocated to your program, not the amount of heap memory that your program is using. Those are two different things.

Comment: @john I think it means the heap memory I used. Because when I create a object and  then free , the heap size will increase and decrese.

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: @IInspectable this is all code except `int main(){}`

Comment: *"This is all the code except, it's not all the code"* is not part of the description of the properties of a [mcve]. Even if you don't understand why, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @IInspectable OK. I have add `int main()` to the code.